# How can I generate and plot a helix that passes through a given point?

Tags: graphing-functions

I need to create and graph an equation of a spiral helix that will pass through the point `{54, 0, 12.5)`, but I am not sure how to attempt this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a math question and not a *Mathematica* question, no?

Comment: Well i guess technically it would be. Do you at least know how to trace along a curve on the graph it will show what my (x,y,z) coordinates are?

Comment: Start the helix at the point (54,0,12.5).  (You can type "helix" into the search field of the documentation center in *Mathematica* to get several helpful pages.)

Comment: I see no good reason to migrate this question to Math.SE

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[
 Column[
   {TextGrid[{{"x", "y", "z"}, 
   v = {Cos[tt], Sin[tt], tt/10}}, 
   Frame -> All], 
   Show[
       ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/10}, {t, 0, 30}], 
       Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[v]}]]},
   Alignment->Center], 
   {tt, 0, 30}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that

```
54 {Cos[t], Sin[t], t/10 + 12.5/54} /. t -> 0
```

gives

> `{54, 0, 12.5}`.

Since

```
54 {Cos[t], Sin[t], t/10 + 12.5/54}
```

is the parametric expression of a helix with radius 54, it represents a helix that solves your problem. This is visualized by

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[54 {Cos[t], Sin[t], t/10 + 12.5/54}, {t, -10, 10}],
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{54, 0, 12.5}, Scaled[.015]]}]]
```

[image: plot]